# Java program hangs on TTransport transport = new THttpClient("this.host.com")

Tags: java, thrift

I'm writing a Thrift application that can take input from an outside website and process it. However, the program is hanging at the line:

```
TTransport transport = new THttpClient("this.host.com");
```

And I'm not sure why it's happening. It's not giving me any error messages and such but it also doesn't progress forward. It just hangs when I receive a request from a client that calls buildModel(). Here's my code:

```
private void buildModel() throws UnknownHostException {
    // Map of user preferences by Mahout user id
    FastByIDMap<Collection<Preference>> userIDPrefMap = new FastByIDMap<Collection<Preference>>();
    System.out.println("Building model");

    try {
        TTransport transport = new THttpClient(this.host);
        TProtocol protocol = new  TBinaryProtocol(transport);
        MyCustomDatabase.Client client = new MyCustomDatabase.Client(protocol);

        ConnectionParams con_params = new ConnectionParams();
        con_params.setUser(this.username);
        con_params.setPassword(this.password);
        Connection con = client.open_connection(con_params);

        ResultSet res = client.execute_sql(con, "select * from " + this.database + "." + this.tableName, null);

        for (Tuple t : res.getTuples()) {
            List<ByteBuffer> cells = t.getCells();
            int userID = Integer.parseInt(new String(cells.get(0).array()));
            int itemID = Integer.parseInt(new String(cells.get(1).array()));
            int ratingValue = Integer.parseInt(new String(cells.get(2).array()));

            Collection<Preference> userPrefs = userIDPrefMap.get(userID);
            if (userPrefs == null) {
                userPrefs = Lists.newArrayListWithCapacity(2);
                userIDPrefMap.put(userID, userPrefs);
            }
            userPrefs.add(new GenericPreference(userID, itemID, ratingValue));
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    this.delegate = new GenericDataModel(GenericDataModel.toDataMap(userIDPrefMap, true));
}
```

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its hard to tell exactly what the issue is but some things to note:

1) `new THttpClient(this.host)` should take a URI string not a host name.  In the Thrift Java library this is the constructor that you are calling:

```
public THttpClient(String url) throws TTransportException {
    try {
      url_ = new URL(url);
      this.client = null;
      this.host = null;
    } catch (IOException iox) {
      throw new TTransportException(iox);
    }
}
```

If you are just passing a host name instead of a URI you probably won't get the results you expect.

2) In the javadoc for the THttpClient class they suggest using the Apache HttpClient constructor instead of the default HttpURLConnection one anyhow, both for better performance and to avoid exhausting the open file descriptor limit under heavy load.

I would suggest that try passing a valid URI to the constructor, and if that does not work try using HttpClient instead, or use both of those measures.